# playing a runtime generated sine wave with Qt 6.4.2

Tags: audio, qt6

I need to play a runtime generated sine wave with Qt 6.4.2
I found many examples, based upon Qt 5, but it seems that in the latest Qt versions, classes like QMediaPlayer and QSoundEffect can only play from files.

Is there a way to play sound from a QByteArray or QBuffer with Qt 6.4.2?

In the examples I've found, QAudioOutput::start(QBuffer* input) is used, but I cannot find it in Qt 6.4.2

Comment: I believe this is dealt with via the `QAudioSink` Class https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qaudiosink.html nowadays

Comment: Thank you, with QAudioSink it works. I add here that, due to a bug on some versions of Qt 6, such as 6.4.2, mfplat.dll must be copied in the exe directory, and renamed in mfplat.dll.dll